# How to get the constraint name from unique key exception thrown by SQL Server in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

With a few columns I created a composite unique key. I want to get those column name from the exception that is thrown by SQL Server.

I tried this one but it does not work.

```
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
            {
                if (ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException is SqlException sqlEx)
                {
                    if (sqlEx.Number == 2601)
                    {
                        // Extract the constraint name from the error message
                        string constraintName = sqlEx.Message.Substring(sqlEx.Message.IndexOf("'") + 1);
                        constraintName = constraintName.Substring(0, constraintName.IndexOf("'"));

                        // Show the constraint name to the user
                        Console.WriteLine($"Violation of unique constraint: {constraintName}");
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting Msg 2601 _Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '%.*ls' with unique index '%.*ls'_ or Msg 2627 _Violation of %ls constraint '%.*ls'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object '%.*ls'_? They are slightly different to parse and neither of them actually contains the column names - you'd have to enumerate those yourself from sys.key_constraints, sys.indexes and sys.index_columns.

Comment: I am getting this message from inner exception:
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'Sales_CollectionFeeSetup_Composite_Unique'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Sales_CollectionFeeSetup'. The duplicate key value is (1, 1, RR, RS, 1, 1.00, 1, 0.00).

Comment: Seems like you're getting Msg 2627 then.

Comment: So you need `if (sqlEx.Number == 2627)` also you can condense it down to `if (ex.InnerException is SqlException sqlEx && sqlEx.Number == 2627)`. Do you also need the column names?

Comment: @Charlieface I just need to get the column names

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are catching the wrong message number

```cs
if (sqlEx.Number == 2627)
```

To retrieve the column names for the constraint, you can use the system views.

```cs
List<string> GetConstraintColumns(string constraintName)
{
    var list = new List<string>();

    const string query @"
SELECT c.name
FROM sys.key_constraints kc
JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = kc.parent_object_id AND i.index_id = kc.unique_index_id
JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = i.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
WHERE kc.name = @constraintName;
";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(YourConnString))
    using (var comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        comm.Parameters.Add("@constraintName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = constraintName;
        using (var reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
            while (reader.Read())
                list.Add((string) reader["name"]);
    }
    return list;
}
```

I would advise you to cache this data in some fashion, as it is unlikely to change over the lifetime of the application. You could remove the parameter and the `WHERE` clause, and store the results in a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`.

---

Note that this does not help you for a unique *index* (as opposed to unique *constraint*), which would have been your original Message 2601. For that you would need to parse both the table name and the index name, and compare with `sys.tables` and `sys.indexes` as opposed to `sys.key_constraints`.