# Get parameters that go into Message from SqlException

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net

.NET 6, WebAPI, ADO.NET, C#. Imagine `SqlException` for unique index violation. The error message goes:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MyTable' with unique index 'IX_Foo'. The duplicate key value is (100, 200).

Is it possible to retrieve the name of the offending index (`IX_Foo`) without parsing the Message string?

It *is* possible to get the error message template from `sys.messages` by the error number and language code, it goes:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '%.*ls' with unique index '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls.

With some string parsing magic it might be possible to locate the %-placeholders and reverse their values; but are they somehow available as it is?

Comment: I don't believe the substitution parameters are exposed. Happy parsing ;-)

Comment: i'm not a c# guru but if you create a regex from the template message and replace %.*ls with capturing groups, it should be pretty easy

Comment: Note that a unique index error is a different message from a unique constraint. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75284865/14868997 for how to get the columns once you have the index name.

Answer (score 1):

To get the English error template from MSSQL, issue the following:
`select text from sys.messages where language_id=1033 and message_id={ErrNo}`
where `ErrNo` specifically for index violation is 2601.

As of MSSQL 2022, the format placeholders in the template generally follow the `printf` pattern, with some caveats. The pattern for those is: %, followed by zero or more `[0123456789.#*-Ilh]`, followed by one of `[dsxXfiucpS!]`.

%% stands for the literal % sign.

'%S' can be only found in special case placeholders %S_DATE, %S_MSG, %S_PGID, %S_PAGE, %S_LSN, %S_BLKIOPTR, %S_TS, %S_TX, %S_RID, %S_XID. Those don't admit format modifiers.

%..! is never found in English error messages.

If parsing in MSSQL, mind the case sensitivity - capital `I` is a format modifier  (as a part of `I64`) while lowercase `i` is a terminal format specifier. Case insensitive parsing logic will confuse the two.

---

It's worth noting that working back from the template to the substitution parameters is not possible in the most general case. For example, if you have template "x%s%sx", it's theoretically impossible to tell whether "xfoobarx" came from "foo" and "bar", or from "f" and "oobar" and so on.

Even in the case of this particular message template, a naive parsing approach might be prone to edge case errors. If the parser assumes, for example, that the third parameter (the duplicate key) ends after a period character, if the period is legitimately a part of that substitution string (e. g. if it's a string key with the value '.'), the parser will misparse that.

---

All that said, in the project that prompted this question I've settled on a middle ground approach. Since all index names in the schema, as a matter of convention, start with `IX_`, I split the error message into SQL identifier-like words and search for the one with the `IX_` prefix:

```
static private readonly Regex s_SQLIdentifier = new Regex("[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*");
//...
SqlError? e = exc.Errors.Cast<SqlError>().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Number == 2601);
if(e != null)
    string TheIndex = s_SQLIdentifier.Matches(e.Message)
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Value.StartsWith("IX_"))?.Value;
```

At least it's stable under (sensible) error message template changes that Microsoft might institute in future versions.

The approach can be generalized for other integrity violation type errors, but the error code will be different, and the constraint naming convention will be different (e. g. "CK_" for check constraints and so on).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way that the parameters are exposed. However, you can make use of the values exposed through `TRY`/`CATCH` and manipulate them to give you something close to what you seem to be looking for. Consider:

```
/*
CREATE TABLE Foo (ID INT, Date DATE);
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Foo ON Foo (ID);
--*/
BEGIN TRY
 INSERT INTO Foo (ID, Date) VALUES (9999999, GETDATE());
 INSERT INTO Foo (ID, Date) VALUES (9999999, GETDATE());
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
 DECLARE @ERROR_LINE INT, @ERROR_MESSAGE NVARCHAR(4000), @ERROR_NUMBER INT, @ERROR_PROCEDURE NVARCHAR(128), @ERROR_SEVERITY INT, @ERROR_STATE INT;
 SET @ERROR_LINE = ERROR_LINE();
 SET @ERROR_MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE();
 SET @ERROR_NUMBER = ERROR_NUMBER();
 SET @ERROR_PROCEDURE = ERROR_PROCEDURE();
 SET @ERROR_SEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY();
 SET @ERROR_STATE = ERROR_STATE();
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('constraint ''',@ERROR_MESSAGE) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@ERROR_MESSAGE,CHARINDEX('constraint ''',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+12, CHARINDEX('''',@ERROR_MESSAGE,CHARINDEX('constraint ''',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+13)- (CHARINDEX('constraint ''',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+12))
            WHEN CHARINDEX('unique index ''',@ERROR_MESSAGE) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(@ERROR_MESSAGE,CHARINDEX('unique index ''',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+14,CHARINDEX('''',@ERROR_MESSAGE,CHARINDEX('unique index ''',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+15)-(CHARINDEX('unique index ''',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+14))
       END AS SubObjectName,
       SUBSTRING(@ERROR_MESSAGE,CHARINDEX('object ''',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+8,CHARINDEX('''',@ERROR_MESSAGE,CHARINDEX('object ''',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+9)-(CHARINDEX('object ''',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+8)) AS ObjectName,
       SUBSTRING(@ERROR_MESSAGE,CHARINDEX('value is (',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+10,CHARINDEX(')',@ERROR_MESSAGE,CHARINDEX('value is (',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+11)-(CHARINDEX('value is (',@ERROR_MESSAGE)+10)) AS Value,
       @ERROR_MESSAGE AS ErrorMessage, @ERROR_NUMBER AS ErrorNumber, @ERROR_PROCEDURE AS ErrorProcedure, @ERROR_SEVERITY AS ErrorSeverity, @ERROR_STATE AS ErrorState
END CATCH
```

This will fail because the second insert attempts to violate the unique index (I also included code to parse in the event the message references a unique constraint). Using some `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` fun we can isolate the meaty parts of the `ERROR_MESSAGE()` and bring them back as columns to use however we need to.

| SubObjectName | ObjectName | Value | ErrorMessage | ErrorNumber | ErrorProcedure | ErrorSeverity | ErrorState |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IX_Foo | dbo.Foo | 9999999 | Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Foo' with unique index 'IX_Foo'. The duplicate key value is (9999999). | 2601 |  | 14 | 1 |

Depending on how you intend to handle the error after the fact, you want want to also include a `THROW` in your `CATCH` block to have the error re-fire once you're done catching/handling it. This won't always be the case, especially in circumstances where you're going to roll forward with it, or take no additional action.

Also, just because it was mentioned in the comments, SQL Server is not the ideal place to perform any sort of string manipulation, while it's possible, there are better options if you return the result sets elsewhere.

If you're going to take some subsequent action in SQL Server it may make sense to do so within it, such as logging the errors to table.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a problem parsing a string, this was a "can this be done better" question rather than a "help me do this" question. The crudest way to do that, anyway, would be to split around ' and take the 4th element :) A better way would be to parse out the placeholders out of the template and follow those.

Comment: Understood, it would be great if there was additional exposure to the parameters that make up the message, but since there isn't and I already had something pre-written to do it, figured it'd be worth posting both for you, and general posterity.

Comment: If you're going to parse the string you might as well do it on the client in C#, where string parsing is much better. You also need to check the error number and conditionaly `THROW;` the exception back.